# How to place a full width paragraph inside a table

Tags: html, css, angular

[image]

I want to place a paragraph inside a table row.

I've tried placing the paragraph inside a `<div>` and placing the `<div>` inside the `<td>` I gave it `display: inline` so as to bring it below the 3 `<td>`'s but that didn't work.

In fact, the `<div>` appears to be the 4th `<td>` and sits inline with the above `<td>`'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you're not supposed to fit paragraph tags as a table row.

If you need a full row of text in between your rows you can do

```
<table>
  <!-- First row with 3 column / 1 column layout -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- Use a table to further split the column -->
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Middle row with paragraph content-->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>{{ Paragraph goes here }}</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Second row with 3 column / 1 column layout -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- Use a table to further split the column -->
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: with certain modifications to your code, I could achieve it. Thank you @IAmQuirkee !!

Comment: np, might want to check how your question is formatted, alot of the `<div>` and `<td>` tags weren't showing so it was kinda confusing x: